# Executing git pull from different directories of different projects but with the same code

Tags: git, github

I want to create multiple projects with the same files but the files are going to be in different locations. I don't have idea how to be able to share same code with multiple projects that basically hasn't the same folder structure (something like I want to do git on subfolder and not on the root folder) so I don't need to take changes manually each time and to paste it in each project I have

**Example:**

> project1: dirA/dirD/src
>
> project2: dirX/dirY/dirZ/dirB/dirH/src
>
> src -> the shared sub folder

Any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a core repository/branch (depending if you're doing single repo or not)

In you core module you will have every files/class/functions you will need for all your projects

Then you create different repository/branch for your different projects which import the core module

Answer (score 0):

You can try [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). Create a new repository for the shared library and then you can include it in different repositories at different paths.

```
git submodule add <shared-code-repository> dirA/dirD/src
```

and

```
git submodule add <shared-code-repository> dirX/dirY/dirZ/dirB/dirH/src
```